# IE7 javascript fails on specific code path, any thoughts?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, ckeditor, fckeditor

So I have an app running CKEditor, or lets just pretend its "just a chunk of javascript".

CKEditor (the javascript) loads fine if I navigate to my app, login, and initalize the editor.

However CKEditor fails if I "remember my login" as it bypasses the login screen.

The two code paths are as follows:

```
1. navigate to site > login > initialize editor    ...WORKS!
2. navigate to site > initialize editor            ...FAILS!
```

The login is a VERY complicated javascript app, so I can't tear it apart, but it is scoped.

The only thing I can think of is some really bizarre load order/timing problem that manifests itself under very specific conditions. Does anyone have any experienced with this kind of issue?

I tried a lot of things. Moving javascript files around, changing load order of scripts, but nothing seems to get case #2 to work.

Open to ideas...

Comment: "Fails" in what way? Does it never replace the `textarea` with CKEditor's WYSIWYG editor in case #2? Do you see any error message(s) in either case #1 or case #2?

Comment: What happens is, for some reason, init methods in the CKEditor fail to load, which results in the script borking out. Throws "onLoad is null" error, which means the onLoad function never got initialized or was overwritten somehow.

Comment: Does it happens only with IE7? I guess that the only option that you might have is to create a testcase and start removing things to get a simplified version to understand exactly what's the difference between the two code paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it is some file path bug with IE7/CKEDTIOR.

This does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

While this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/js/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

What a joke. Wasted 6 days trying to figure it out!